# How to hide Backoffice nodes including some product nodes?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am using SAP Commerce Cloud 19.05 in my B2C project.We have certain custom itemtypes like:

1. `XYZCompanyProduct`(extends `Product`)
2. `XYZLaptopProduct`(extends `XYZCompanyProduct`)
3. `XYZMobileProduct`(extends `Product`)

Now in the explorer tree, we have three nodes corresponding to the above nodes. We want certain users to have access to `XYZLaptopProduct` and `Orders` and `Consignment` nodes and other nodes to be hidden when the user logs in.

We tried several ways of achieving this like:

1. We created a Backoffice role for the laptop product users and a corresponding group to it(say `laptopGroups`).
2. In the `groups` section of `laptopGroups` we gave it access to `backofficeproductmanagergroup` and the above role.
3. The above step caused it to have access to multiple other product nodes, as well(like `XYZCompanyProduct` and `XYZMobileProduct`) which is unwanted behaviour.
4. I tried removing the nodes by:

   `<context component="explorer-tree" merge-by="principal" principal="laptopGroups">
         <!-- other nodes... -->
       <navigation-node id="Restricted" merge-mode="remove"/>
   </context>`

These steps seem to be all failing. Where am I going wrong? Should I approach this in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your objective, you can use **permission in backoffice framework**. Using that, you can restrict specific ItemType or it's specific attributes access to any particular user/groups in backoffice.

You can achieve the same by 2 ways :

1. From backoffice directly --> `backoffice > go to user groups >> click on key symbol (permissions) >> select your item type >> give required permissions`
2. Or using impex (sample as below)

```
$START_USERRIGHTS; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;

Type      ; UID          ; Target           ; read ; change ; create ; remove ;
UserGruop ; laptopGroups ; XYZLaptopProduct ; +     ;   -   ;   -    ;   -    ;

$END_USERRIGHTS; ; ; ; ;
```

Refer following for more details on above 2 approaches :

https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8c282d8686691014b54f95ffbf322a6b.html

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8be36d438669101497eeed8ff7b712fe.html

Hope it helps!